# Page header with chapter title but without number (KOMA-Script)

Tags: sectioning, numbering, chapters, koma-script

Now that I have turned numbering on, `\leftmark` shows chapter title with number in my header. like

> 1 ChapterTitle

How do I remove the number?

these are my settings

```
documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english,openany,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[nouppercase,headsepline,footsepline,automark]{scrpage2}
\clearscrheadfoot
\clearscrheadings
\chead{}
\cfoot{}
\ihead{HeaderLeftText}
\ohead{HeaderRightText}
\ifoot{\rule{0pt}{\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox}\SomeChapterNameCommand} % want chapter name here
\ofoot{\rule{0pt}{\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox}\thepage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
```

Comment: How exactly are you building your headers? Provide a minimal working code.

Comment: No.. I only want to remove the chapter number from the footer text, not the chapter itself.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In case of the KOMA-Script classes, the formatting of the chapter number in the headline is controlled by `\chaptermarkformat.` To get rid of the chapter number, you simply have to redefine `\chaptermarkformat` as:

```
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}
```

Comment: this answer and \headmark works!

Answer (score 2):

Try redefining `\chaptermark`:

```
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
```

If that doesn't work, please add to your question some minimal working code showing the relevant settings involved in the header generation.

Comment: does not work.. added settings