# Remove section number in header

Tags: header-footer

I'd like to have a header where the current section is centered but without the section-number. 
In the following example the header looks like "1 Example" but I'd like to have "Example".

```
\documentclass[headsepline, footsepline]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\begin{document}
\clearscrheadfoot
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\automark[section]{section}
\ihead[University]{University}
\chead[\rightmark]{\rightmark}
\ohead[Author]{Author}
\ifoot[\today]{\today}
\ofoot{\thepage}
\section{Example}
Text
\end{document}
```

Is that anyhow possible?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you mean the section title "header" or the page header, usually called 'living column title'?

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm not that familiar with the correct namings. I guess I mean the page header. The text between (in this case) University and Author.

Comment: indeed - see the link in my comment. in short: add `\renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{}` in your preamble and you should get the section name without the number in the header

Comment: Wow, you're a genius. That's it. So easy. Thank you so much for your quick response. You really helped me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the idea found in [Chapter title without number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26043/chapter-title-without-number), the solution to your problem is to insert

```
\renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{}
```

in the preamble (for instance after `\usepackage{scrpage2}`). This removes the number in the header.

Comment: How would I do the same only for select chapters/sections, e.g. the references at the end of a book? Inserting the commands in the document results in an error.

Comment: I haven't tested this now, but I think you could change the pagestyle to plain (or similar) before the chapter/section you want to remove using '\pagestyle{plain}'