# Hide chapter prefix in KOMA-Script headers

Tags: header-footer, koma-script

I am using KOMA-Script with the `scrbook` class. I want all my chapters *headings* prefixed with "Chapter", but I don't want the "Chapter" prefix in *headers*. I can't figure out how to change the headers.

I only want to remove the prefix here (top of each page):

[image]

But I want to keep the prefix here:

[image]

Here is the code. A pure KOMA-script solution is preferable.

```
\documentclass[headings=standardclasses, oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{My Chapter Title}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation ([Ch. 5](https://ctan.net/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#page=274) "Headers and footers")? You need to redefine `\chaptermarkformat`: `\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}`. The default is `\chapappifchapterprefix{\ }\thechapter\autodot\enskip`, yielding "Chapter 1   My Chapter Title" as in your example.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Chapter title without number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26099/)

Comment: Thank you! I searched and searched in the documentation, but couldn't find this! How do I close this as a duplicate?

Comment: No need, moderators or high-rep users will see to it in due time.

Comment: For me with `scrreprt`, `\chaptermarkformat` has no effect. I use
`\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\thechapter\autodot\enskip#1}{}}`.